# Naming hive session cannot work sometimes

Tags: hive, apache-tez, hive-configuration

I ran sqls on hive tez by `hive -f xxx.sql --hiveconf hive.session.id=sessionName`
but on the yarn resourcemanager  displays like this

```
HIVE-f4ea6c3f-f4cf-4db3-8801-da6f94e20237
HIVE-d920c434-d2e6-4c1c-a506-d69b580960f7
```

sometimes it displays correctly..
How can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The thing is Tez can reuse containers. AM container reuse = session reuse. controlled by this parameter: `tez.am.container.reuse.enabled=true`

One yarn AM container can be reused for different Tez sessions. This is the reason why yarn name is different.

BTW there is one more parameter added in this JIRA [HIVE-12357](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12357), you can set name for each DAG:

```
hive.query.name
```

Comment: yes,I set tez.am.container.reuse.enabled=false also not work ,If i set hive.query.name I need to search info in tez ui not yarn